# Semantic-UI Multiple selection with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms, semantic-ui

I want to use JS library "Semantic-UI" with my PHP code

I want to replace the ordinary select boxes with "Semantic-UI Multiple selection Dropdown"

The original PHP Code that generates the Select items:

```
<div class="list-group">
             <h3>Material</h3>
             <?php
              $query = "SELECT DISTINCT(product_gender) FROM product";
              $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
              $statement->execute();
              $result = $statement->fetchAll();
              foreach($result as $row)
              {
              ?>
              <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                  <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector gender" value="<?php echo $row['product_gender']; ?>"  > <?php echo $row['product_gender']; ?></label>
              </div>
              <?php
              }
              ?>
          </div>
```

I want to replace input with Semantic-UI :

```
  <div class="list-group">
             <h3>Gender</h3>
             <select multiple="" class="label ui selection fluid dropdown">
             <?php
              $query = "SELECT DISTINCT(product_gender) FROM product";
              $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
              $statement->execute();
              $result = $statement->fetchAll();
              foreach($result as $row)
              {
              ?>
              <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                <option name='gender' class="common_selector gender" value="<?php echo $row['product_gender']; ?>"><?php echo $row['product_gender']; ?></option>
              </div>
              <?php
              }
              ?>
              </select>
          </div>
```

It gathers the options, But didn't post data, since the function that posts data is :

```
<script>
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
filter_data();

function filter_data()
{
    $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
    var action = 'fetch_data';
    var es2 = get_filter('es2');
    var bw2 = get_filter('bw2');
    var tl = get_filter('tl');
    var b2 = get_filter('b2');
    var gender = get_filter('gender');
    var material = get_filter('material');
    var hinge = get_filter('hinge');

    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_data.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{action:action, es2:es2, bw2:bw2, tl:tl, b2:b2, gender:gender, material:material, hinge:hinge},
        success:function(data){
            $('.filter_data').html(data);
        }
    });
}
function get_filter(class_name)
{
    var filter = [];
    $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
        filter.push($(this).val());
    });
    return filter;
}

$('.common_selector').click(function(){
    filter_data();
});
```

});

And we get Data by this :

```
if(isset($_POST["gender"]))
{

    $gender_filter = implode("','", $_POST["gender"]);
    $query .= "
     AND product_gender IN('".$gender_filter."')
    ";
}
if(isset($_POST["material"]))
{
```

So please how can I merge Semantic-UI with my code ?

Comment: Why is there a `div` element inside your `select`, around the `options`? That is invalid HTML to begin with, the `div` has no business being there.